# How to check Drupal distribution version from CLI?

Tags: drush

I have OpenAtrium2 instance and I want to check it version from CLI.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Just run the following command from the root directory of your Open Atrium installation:

```
drush status-report
```

This should give you the output similar to the status report screen in the standard Drupal backend. In my Open Atrium installation, one of the lines reads:

```
Install profile            Info      OpenAtrium (openatrium-7.x-2.18)
```

So in this case I'm running Open Atrium version 2.18.

Comment: Cool, that something but can I get only version without rest of the information, so I can process it further in e.g. script?


 It would be great to have same functionality like in core-status for drupal version: 
 ``$ drush st --format=list drupal_version`` ->
 ``7.24``

Comment: I found this `drush status-report --fields=description | grep OpenAtrium | cut -c25- | cut -d')' -f1` but it's not ideal